# Google sheets multiple dependant lists dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula

I'm collecting data in a sheet from people so they can categorise the product types. I have a sheet with thousands of products in rows. For each product i want to know the Type and sub-type for each product.

For e.g. If type is `Apparel` then the sub-type (dependant dropdown) shows data based on Apparel options.

[image: Apparel options]

If type is `Accessories` then the sub-type shows relevant data.

[image: Accessories options]

What i'm able to do is when i select a type, the sub-type column data changes based on that, but i want to make it a drop-down list so a relevant sub-type can be selected for that row.
[image: Subtype]

Would really love and appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: another way is to use script

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with named ranges and `INDIRECT` function.

Based on the example below.
[image]

First you will have to name the ranges, go to 'Data' -> 'Named Ranges', select the cells that have the apparels, name that range 'Apparel' and do the same with the other lists.

Create the first drop-down that lists Apparel/Accessories,etc. as the options. In this case the range I used is `=A1:B1`.

Before you create the other drop-down, go to an empty cell or create another sheet and enter the following formula `=INDIRECT(D1)`.

Now you can insert the second drop-down next to the first one. In the data validation criteria specify the cells that contain the result from the `INDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer of Google here : https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135968271/multiple-dependent-drop-down-list?hl=en

But in this solution, you have to know the content of the first list to enter a formula with these values.

If your aim is to have that :

- A first dynamic drop-down list (as named range)
- Multiple dynamic drop-down lists (as named ranges), depending of the value selected in the first drop-down

You can do it with code by following this tutorial : https://medium.com/p/354f87503ce1